# Get-ScheduledJob trim Command property

Tags: string, powershell, scheduled-tasks

In my function for scheduling server reboots, there is a ViewOnly ParamSet and I'm trying to take the output of `(Get-ScheduledJob).command` which resembles `Reboot.ps1 -server YourServer9000 | Out-File -Force \\SysLogSvr\d$\YourServer9000-Reboot.log` and extract the `log` string to open it for the user.

I've been trying to use `((Get-ScheduledJob).command).Trim(4)` which doesn't appear to be doing anything.  As a test, I tried `((Get-ScheduledJob).command).ToUpper()` which correctly displays the output in all caps.

Comment: Your command does not starts nor ends with `[char]4`, it does not contain `[char]4` at all. What do you expect from `.Trim(4)`?

Comment: I was expecting to use `(Get-ScheduledJob).Command` to output a string that can be trimmed so I can pipe the output to `Invoke-Item`